# Access 2010 SQL Update cmd

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having some difficulty with an Update statement.

```
UPDATE DownPeriod 
SET 
DownPeriod.EquipmentID = ? ?? ?? ? ??  ?? ? ?,
DownPeriod.DownDate = Forms!Edit!EditDownDateBox,
DownPeriod.DownTime = Forms!Edit!EditDownTimeBox, 
DownPeriod.[UpDate] = Forms!Edit!EditUpDateBox, 
DownPeriod.UpTime = Forms!Edit!EditUpTimeBox, 
DownPeriod.isScheduled = Forms!Edit!EditSchedCheck, 
DownPeriod.isUnscheduled = Forms!Edit!EditUnschedCheck, 
DownPeriod.Comments = Forms!Edit!EditCommentsDropDown
WHERE DownPeriod.DownPeriodID =Forms!Edit!RecordHistorySubform.Form!DownPeriodID;
```

Where the question marks are is where im having difficulty, and am not sure what to put.

Everything else about the update will work if I remove that statement so I know im on the right track. The difference with the EquipmentID is that I'm getting this value based on an input for another table entry. To elaborate the user chooses an Equipment Title, which is another field in my Equip Table that will relate to a unique ID.

So far I have tried DLOOKUP("[EquipmentID]", "Equipment", "[Title] = Forms!Edit!EditEquipmentDropDown")
Select statment and 
using inner join
I'm at a loss and need help plz! 
Thank you!

Comment: This is for an edit form that allows a user to view records and change any data from a particular record. In this case the DownPeriod table stores a foreign key EquipmentID from the Equipment table. The edit box however displays a more informative equipment title, another field of the equipment table, rather then some meaningless ID tag. So what I would like is for the EquipmentID to change but the user looks as tho they are changing the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the user is selecting the title from a dropdown. The dropdown should have a row source on these lines:

```
  SELECT ID, Title FROM Equipment
```

With ID as a hidden column. Your update should then be:

```
 DownPeriod.EquipmentID = Forms!Edit!EditTitleDropDown
```

As an aside, I suspect you are doing a lot more work that you need to do to make an MS Access form work.

Comment: That seem'd like it should have worked but its not, I dont understand why. I don't think its overly complicated I have the user select a start and end date. A subform is populated with a list of records that fall within the criteria. They may then select a record upon which severl boxes are populated with the record and are allowed to be edited.

Comment: What is the row source of your drop down and what is the bound column?

Comment: Even using the immediate window gives the right value but it doesn't seem to accept it in the query

Comment: Test with a dummy value. DownPeriod.EquipmentID = 2. Use the query design window and see what it complains about.

Comment: yes calling the query with t static value does work as it should.

Comment: It works! FINALLY! I kept playing around with things and it eventually came throough, Thank you to you both for helping me out, Cheers. @lazfish

Answer (score 1):

If it is a new unique id you need an INSERT. If it already exists you should include it as part of your WHERE clause.

WHERE DownPeriod.DownPeriodID =Forms!Edit!RecordHistorySubform.Form!DownPeriodID
AND DownPeriod.EquipmentID = Forms!Edit!EditEquipmentDropDown;

Comment: this is not a new record, that is for something else. I tried including additional criteria in the WHERE but it failed to work.    Equipment.Title = Forms!Edit!EditEquipmentDropDown  was the criteria.